# How to map data from Axios in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, object, axios, mapping

I'm using Axios to get data from an API.
I want to loop through all the items in a feed fetch with Axios using map function and get there title. But I don't know how to map it because my feed is structure like `items[0].title`, `items[1].title`...

```
const URL = 'https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fvnexpress.net%2Frss%2Fthe-gioi.rss';

    let content = null;
    const [feed, setFeed] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
            setFeed(response.data);
        });
    }, [URL]);

if(feed) {
     /// To get title of first item: content = <Text>{feed.items[0].title}
    content = 
            
                feed.map(f => {
                return <Text>{f.items[???].title}</Text>   /// How to loop through all the items[0].title, items[1].title, items[2].title ?
                })
            
}

return (<View>{content}</View>);
```

EDIT;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you got array of Feed

```
const URL = 'https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fvnexpress.net%2Frss%2Fthe-gioi.rss';

    let content = null;
    const [feed, setFeed] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
            setFeed(response.data);
        });
    }, [URL]);

if(feed) {
     /// To get title of first item: content = <Text>{feed.items[0].title}
    content = () => {
      feed.map((f) => {
        return (
          <View>
            {feed.items.map((item) => {
              return <Text>{item.title}</Text>;
            })}
          </View>
        );
      });
    };
            
}

return (<View>{content && content()}</View>);
```

```
const content = () => {
      feeds.map((f) => {
        return (
          <View>
            {feeds.items.map((item) => {
              return <Text>{item.title}</Text>;
            })}
          </View>
        );
      });
    };
```

If always you get a single Feed

```
content = 
            
                 (<View>{feed.items.map(item)=> {
                   return<Text>{item.title}</Text> 
                 }}</View>)
```

Comment: what is your case array of feeds ? and what error u got

Comment: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`

Comment: first of all, when I copy paste your code (the array of feed one) in, it says "content is declared but its value is never read". Second of all, when I save and refresh, it gives warning "possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0)"

Comment: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: execute the content()

Comment: TypeError: content is not a function (in 'content()', content is null)

Comment: undefined is not a function (near '...feed.map...')

Comment: change feeds to feed

Comment: sadly, undefined is not a function (near '...feed.map...')

Comment: print what feed object looks like

Comment: check ediited question, I added a screen shot, the feed is at bottom right